# How to center div vertically in other div

Tags: html, css

In my code I have section element with a background image and I want to put a div element over that like this[image]

But I dont know how to put that text over the image. It just sticks over it:
Here is my html and css:

```css
* {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-size: 22px;
  
}

#mission {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url(https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#mission div {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<section id="mission">
  <div>
    <h2>Our Mission</h2>
    <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: The only way to propely do this is with the [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/). This works also when you don't know the height of the element. It's [supported by all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/flexbox), and even internet Explorer.

Comment: @Pieterjan I am not sure how you mean that. Should I just assign `display: flex;` to `<section>` ?

Comment: Normally yes. `display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;`

Comment: 2021, we are many to have no clues, no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the text position: relative

```css
* {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-size: 22px;
  
}

#mission {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url(https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#mission div {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;

}
.text { position: relative; top: 310px} /* or use calc() to find better placement */
```

```html
<section id="mission">
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Our Mission</h2>
    <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for that answer. It solved my problem.. partly. I dont know why, but somehow now the image isn't appearing any more and there is just a single black background. I checked and it is not from the div element. Do you have any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: As you can see in the snippet, it works here. So perhaps I am useing a class you use for something else

Answer (score 0):

just use bootstrap
google how to use bootstrap if you havnt used it yet.

so for the answer what we just call  `class="my-auto"` on the div

Comment: This requires the height of the child to be explicitly defined

Comment: yes thats right